# Get text to center between float left and float right div even when window resizes?

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-float

How the heck to I get a piece of text to center between 2 divs that are floated left and right?

My code is below

```
<style type="text/css">
.left {
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    padding-right:10px;
}

</style>
<div id="header">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Stuff on the left</p>
    </div>

    <span>Center Text or Image/Logo</span>

    <div class="right">
        <p>Stuff on the right</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change span to div and float:left all 3 divs

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Stuff on the left</p>
    </div>
   <div class="center">
        <p>Stuff in the center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Stuff on the right</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float:left;    
    width:25%;
}
.right {
    float:left;    
    width:25%;
}
.center {
    float:left;  
    width:49%;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cyR5W/